# simple_form default collection if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my simple form, I would like to refer to a collection, and have the following behaviour:

- if the field is blank, use a specified default from the collection
- allow the user to drop down a set of valid values
- if the record has been persisted, then display the saved value as default

So far my code is this (also using simple_enum)

```
    <%= f.input :back_language, 
                collection: enum_option_pairs(Flashcard, :back_language), 
                label: false, 
                selected: current_user.fluent_language %>
```

How do I set a default value that doesn't overwrite the saved values ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `current_user.fluent_language` for `back_language` field. Shouldn't it be the same property?

Comment: @PetrGazarov that is correct, it's loading a default from the user's record. The problem is this code is overwriting values which are there on an Edit, and that's not how I'd like it to work. I'd like to default only if the field is blank (New or Edit)

Comment: Are you using an input for a dropdown?

Comment: @GustavoRubio yes I am using this for a dropdown. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ardochhigh a select_tag maybe?

Comment: Why on earth would this question attract a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**EDIT:**

Turns out Reform has an easy way to implement this. :)

When calling `property` in the form object, just pass in the `default` option.

```
property :back_language, default: model.fluent_language
```

Voila!

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

When using `simple_form` with `reform`, behind the hood the form object defines getters and setters when you call `property`. These methods get delegated to the `model`, but you can override them if you need to populate the form differently or manipulate form data before saving.

In your case, you would want to override the getter method for `back_language`.

In your template you will just have:

```
<%= f.input :back_language, 
            collection: enum_option_pairs(Flashcard, :back_language), 
            label: false %>
```

The form object will have:

```
model :user
property :back_language

def back_language
  # takes care of both new and edit actions
  super || model.fluent_language
end
```

**ALTERNATIVELY**

If you don't want to deal with form object, you could do this:

```
<%= f.input :back_language, 
            collection: enum_option_pairs(Flashcard, :back_language), 
            label: false, 
            selected: (@form.back_language || current_user.fluent_language) %>
```

But I don't advise to keep logic in your template.

Comment: I'll probably go to a form object eventually, and I can see that this will work. I'm a bit surprised there isn't a less verbose solution with simple_form. Should I be using a select_tag as @Gustavo Rubio suggested?

Comment: @ardochhigh I don't think `select_tag` is meant to be used with simple_form (simple_form makes it unnecessary)

Comment: I think at first I misunderstood your question - thought that you wanted to never display blank value (event when model is persisted). I updated the getter logic, so it will always display the data when model persisted, even if `""`.

Comment: I investigated a bit more, looks like reform has `default` option for this purpose. I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to just set the value of `current_user.fluent_language` if it's not present yet without saving it:

```
<% current_user.fluent_language ||= "you_default_value" %>
<%= f.input :back_language, 
            collection: enum_option_pairs(Flashcard, :back_language), 
            label: false, 
            selected: current_user.fluent_language %>
```

---

*Edit:*
I'm not sure what your implementations of `fluent_language` and `back_language` like, but according to a comment a probably better solution would be somehting like this:

```
<% current_user.back_language ||= "you_default_value" %>
<%= f.input :back_language, 
            collection: enum_option_pairs(Flashcard, :back_language), 
            label: false %>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? `current_user.fluent_language` will still replace users persisted `back_language` on edit